# How to solve "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"? (Vue.JS 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

My component is like this :

```
methods: {
    reloadMessage() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.$http.get(window.BaseUrl + '/message/inbox');
        }, 1500);
    }
}
```

My routes is like this :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'message','as'=>'messeage.'],function(){
    Route::get('inbox', ['as'=>'inbox','uses'=>'MessageController@index']);
});
```

When the code executed, there exist error like this :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lost context, 
Use bind:

```
methods: {
    reloadMessage() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.$http.get(window.BaseUrl + '/message/inbox');
        }.bind(this), 1500);
    }
}
```

or arrow function:

```
methods: {
    reloadMessage() {
        setTimeout(() => this.$http.get(window.BaseUrl + '/message/inbox'), 1500);
    }
}
```

Comment: why this should ? It is just request for the data, you should update something using this data. https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

Comment: Seems I was wrong to ask. But thanks for you help. Now, I had solve it